# Drag and drop category error

Tags: magento2, category, javascript, category-tree

I get `There was a category move error.` on moving(drag and drop) subcategory to another root category. How I debug this?

on console I get `Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom`

this seems to be related to this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3171

but on development works!!

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this problem. The only way I can get a sub category drag and drop to save is if I click on the sub category I want to move, wait for the page to refresh - THEN drag the sub category to the new location, followed by clicking the SAVE CATEGORY button.

Any other procedure does not save the move. Hopefully this will be fixed soon in Magento 2 for those who get really nervous applying patches for fear of crashing the installation.